# Max and min of function on another function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I solved the optimisation problem, max and min of
$$ f(x,y)=2x+2y$$
On
$$ g(x,y) = x^2+y^2-y=0$$
And got the following points
$$ (\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} , \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} + \frac{1}{2} ) , (\frac{-1}{\sqrt{8}} , \frac{-1}{\sqrt{8}} + \frac{1}{2} ) $$
To understand the problem in a better way i plotted the functions and the points,
[image]
But can't really understand how is max and min the black points (A,B) and not the green ones?
The black ones are not even on $f(x,y)$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you've plotted "the functions", it looks like you've plotted two quite different things:

On the one hand, you've plotted $$z = f(x,y)$$

which is a plane.

On the other hand, you've plotted the surface $$g(x,y)=0$$ in three dimensions.

Now, you didn't have to go to three dimensions - the problem doesn't state there's any variables except $x$ and $y$. It just asks you to find the $x$ and $y$ that minimise and maximise $2x+2y$. The solution to that problem will be some values for $x$ and $y$, namely, the points you found:

$$(x,y)=\left(-\frac1{\sqrt{8}},\frac{2-\sqrt2}{4}\right),$$
and
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt{8}},\frac{2+\sqrt2}{4}\right).$$

Those are your black points: the $(x,y)$ points that optimise $f$ subject to the constraint.

If the question was "find the x and y, and the value of $f(x,y)$", well, then each solution would have a value of $x$, a value of $y$, and a value of $f$, which can be thought of (if we like) as distance along a third axis: the $z$ axis if we say $z=f(x,y)$. Then, the two optima are

$$(x,y,f)=\left(-\frac1{\sqrt{8}},\frac{2-\sqrt2}{4},1-\sqrt2\right),$$
and
$$(x,y,f)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt{8}},\frac{2+\sqrt2}{4},1+\sqrt2\right).$$

Those are your green points, directly above the black ones, since the black ones just record the optimal $x$ and $y$, but not the optimal value.